# How to generate unique sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve [377. Combination Sum 4](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/).

```
Output: 7
Explanation:
The possible combination ways are:
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 3)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 1)
```

Here's my solution so far:

```
class Solution(object):

    def combinationSum4(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        result = []
        def dfs(i, curr, total):
            # print(i)
            if total==target:
                result.append(curr[::])
                return
            if total>target or i>=len(nums):
                return
            curr.append(nums[i])
            dfs(i, curr, total+nums[i])
            curr.pop()
            dfs(i+1,curr,total)

        dfs(0,[],0)
        print(result)
        return len(result)
```

It generates only one of (1,1,2),(1,2,1)(2,1,1) solutions or one of (1,3)(3,1). I am not sure how to construct the recursive tree such that all solutions would be produced. In general, how to think about building recursive trees for different solutions, like unique combinations (which would contain just one of the above possible solutions), unique sequences etc.? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did u try dynamic programming

Comment: I know that's the most optimal solution but I want to understand how I can do it using recursion.

Comment: Pure recursion will be too slow, but you can speed it up with `functools.cache` as Marks says. Which is essentially DP in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you unwind the recursion here `dfs(i, curr, total+nums[i])` you move onto `dfs(i+1,curr,total)` which means you never have the option to consider places where where `i` is included in the results after `i+1`. So solutions like `(2, 1, 1)` won't be found.

I suspect you will want to rethink the whole approach because some combinations like `nums = (4, 2, 1)` and `target = 32` will have on the order of 40 million combinations. You probably don't want to create all those huge lists when you just need a total amount.

To use recursion you can do something like:

```
class Solution: 
    def combinationSum4(self, nums, target):
        def dfs(nums, t):
            if t == 0:
                return 1
            if t < 0:
                return 0
            return sum(dfs(nums, t-n) for n in nums)

        return dfs(tuple(nums), target)
```

But this will likely be too slow for input with a large solution. A simple way to speed it up significantly is to use a cache so you don't look for `nums = (1)` `target=3` and the like a hundred million times. The easy way to do that is with [`functools cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) and putting `@cache` above the `dfs` function. Probably won't be award-winning speed, but might get you started.

Comment: thank you so much! I have glossed over your solution but I will try to understand by writing the logic down. I understand dp is the best possible solution but I also wanted to understand how I could write this using recursion - it's purely for my own learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, we can use dynamic programming. We can define an array dp where dp[i] represents the number of possible combinations that add up to i. Initially, all elements of dp are set to 0 except for dp[0] which is set to 1 (since there is only one way to make 0, which is by not selecting any element).

For each element in nums, we iterate through the dp array and update the values of dp[i] where i is greater than or equal to the current element. We update dp[i] by adding dp[i - current element] to it. This is because if we can make i - current element using the elements in nums, we can make i by adding the current element to that combination.

Finally, we return dp[target], which represents the number of possible combinations that add up to target.

Here's the code:

```
class Solution:
def combinationSum4(self, nums, target):
    dp = [0] * (target + 1)
    dp[0] = 1
    
    for i in range(1, target + 1):
        for num in nums:
            if i >= num:
                dp[i] += dp[i - num]
    
    return dp[target]
```